Axios POST Request with Refresh Token Not Received by Backend (MERN Stack)
I'm encountering an issue where a POST request made with Axios in my frontend application using React.Js isn't delivering the refreshToken to my backend API (Node.js and Express). I'm using the MERN stack.
Frontend code:
const refresh = () => {
  axios
    .post("/v1/users/refresh-token", { refreshToken })
    .then((response) => {
      setAuth((prev) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(prev));
        console.log(response.data.data.accessToken);
        return { ...prev, accessToken: response.data.data.accessToken };
      });
      return response.data.data.accessToken;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};

return refresh;
};

Backend Code: not complete but the relevent part of the code
const refreshAccessToken = asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
    const incomigRefreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken || req.body.refreshToken;
    console.log(req.body)
    
    console.log(incomigRefreshToken);

    if(!incomigRefreshToken)
        throw new ApiError(401,"Unauthorized Access");

I tried console logging;
the refresh Token is there on frontend but not there in backend its just empty object {} in req.body.
I tried using fetch instead of axios same issue as above.

Lets try with this payload .post("/v1/users/refresh-token", { refreshToken: "dummy" })

It ma be possible that the req.body returns promise based answer.
Instead of req.body try using req.json()
Your new code will looks like
const refreshAccessToken = asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{

    const { refreshToken } = await req.json();
    console.log(refreshToken);

    if(!refreshToken)
        throw new ApiError(401,"Unauthorized Access");

    // rest of your code...
}



TypeError: req.json is not a function
